# Contextual filter by taxonomy terms

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a two taxonomy vocabulary labeled as "Region and Category". Also made this as entity reference to a custom content type.

Now, I created a view of contents of "Business Page" and I want to create a contextual filter by taxonomy term, both Region and Category.

Temporarily, what I did is just focus on one taxonomy, by Region, to test if it works.

Please see images below for my configuration:

[image]

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]

My problem it is only working on term ID and not term Name.

I want to input the term Name and result would display on the page.

PS: I have a Pathauto enabled and added URL aliases to each terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this simple answer: [How to use use Term:Name as a contextual filter](https://www.drupal.org/node/1156022#comment-4469378)

Comment: I try it, but didnt work. Right now I have view of the content type, and a relationship with the taxonomy term. I can add any field from the taxonomy, but can not include the relationship in the contextual filter.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain better Johnn's answer and relative link.

1. add a relation to your View. Something like **Taxonomy term referenced by field_my_taxonomy** (you may want to make this required)
2. add a Contextual Filter to **Name** (Taxonomy term). Check Relationship is set to your taxonomy reference field (field_my_taxonomy in my example)
3. the key setting is: When the filter is NOT in the URL: **Raw values extracted from URL**, select position by your pattern and check "Use path alias"

You may want to specify the **evalutation method Taxonomy term NAME** (not ID), selecting the vocabulary.

If term names can contain spaces you should check the option to transform them in "-" and for pretty looking titles you can use the "Uppercase/Lowercase" thing.